# Win 8.1 phone application not working when fiddler on

Tags: fiddler, windows-phone-8-emulator, fiddlercore

I have a win 8.1 phone application which makes https calls continuously.

I am using Visual studio 2013 Update 4 and on Win 8.1 phone emulator.
I am able to sniff requests of IE in emulator, also windows store requests.

But my application is not working when fiddler is on, It only establishes the connection with my server and that's it.doesn't work afterwards.
works fine when it is off.
my proxy setting in the network connections is my ip :8889. This is the same address depicted in the fiddler options.

**UPDATE**
Same problem is with Win 8.1 Phone also

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462697/windows-phone-8-1-emulator-not-proxying-through-fiddler

Comment: thanks Marton for the reply. Have tried all those but no luck