# Issues with posting JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1

So on my client (windows phone 8.1 app) I have posted a JSON just for testing, here is the code for this:

```
    public async void SendJSON()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=karim";

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                         httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
            {
                //create some json string
                string json = "{ \"my\" : \"json\" }";

                // convert json to byte array
                byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

                // Write the bytes to the stream
                await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Now I'm trying to figure out, from the www.myurl.com how would I retrieve what has been posted from the mobile app using a Web Service?

**UPDATE**

When I debug these lines, it runs perfectly without breaking nor falling within the catch. However when looking at where it should post to (the results are here http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2015/12/14/karim/) it doesn't post anything.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

BTW: it already has results there because I have done this directly from my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see, what have you send, you can use this http://posttestserver.com

Otherwise there is not easy way how to force some endpoint to retrieve data. There must but set up server, which is allowing it, proccessing it, storing it etc.

---

If you POST anything to http://posttestserver.com/post.php it will return you this message

> Successfully dumped 0 post variables. View it at
>   http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2015/12/15/00.19.29177030164 Post
>   body was 134 chars long.

So just print somewhere your response and you will get the exact url

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but if you want to inspect your http requests fiddler is a good choice. Since your are using windows phone apps you can configure the windows phone emulator to proxy through fiddler.

Here is a blog post how to set this up: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/06/05/configure-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-work-with-fiddler.aspx - Configure the Windows Phone 8 Emulator to work with Fiddler

// **Edit**: Have you considered to use `HttpClient`

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
string resourceAddress = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=karim"; 
            string postBody = "{ \"my\" : \"json\" }"
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Code is from the top of my head so you might have to tweak it... and of course you need to handle error cases and/or retry, etc
HTH

Answer (score -1):

You should use fiddler to see the outputted content:
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

[Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator not proxying through Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462697/windows-phone-8-1-emulator-not-proxying-through-fiddler)